# Django updating or inserting duplicated rows

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I create several forms to edit some records. When I save the form, I can see in the database that the application update the record and insert one or two record more.

All the forms that I use to update record have this weird behavior. I don't know if the error is in the form definition or in the view definition.

#### Model

```
class DetalleRecepcion(models.Model):
    id_proveedor = models.ForeignKey(Proveedor,db_column='id_proveedor',primary_key=True,      verbose_name='Proveedor')
    anio = models.IntegerField( null=False)
    mes = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Mes')
    fecha_recepcion = models.DateField(verbose_name='Fecha Recepcion')
    usuario = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True)
    num_archivos = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, verbose_name='No de archivos')

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'mpc_detalle_recepcion'
```

#### View

```
@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def DetRecView(request):
    idp = request.GET.get('i')
    anio = request.GET.get('a')
    mes = request.GET.get('m')
    if request.method == 'POST':
       r = DetalleRecepcion.objects.get(id_proveedor=idp,anio=anio,mes=mes)
       form = DetRecForm(request.POST or None, instance =r)
       if form.is_valid():
          form.save()
          return HttpResponse('<script type="text/javascript">window.close()</script>')
    else:
       r = DetalleRecepcion.objects.get(id_proveedor=idp,anio=anio,mes=mes)
       r.usuario = request.user
       form = DetRecForm(instance=r)

    return render_to_response('detrec.html',
                              {'form':form},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

#### Form

```
class DetRecForm(forms.ModelForm):
      fecha_recepcion = forms.DateField(widget=DateInput(),)
      def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
          super(DetRecForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
          self.helper = FormHelper(self)
          self.helper.layout = Layout(
           Field('id_proveedor',
                 'anio',
                 'mes',
                 'usuario',
                 readonly = True
                 ),
           Fieldset('',
                    'fecha_recepcion',
                    'num_archivos',
                    Submit('save','Grabar'),
                    HTML('<a class="btn btn-danger" id="cerrar">Cancelar</a>')
                    )
          )
      class Meta:
          model = DetalleRecepcion
```

I am using a legacy database, I check the constrains, procedure, triggers of the database and everything look fine.
Beside the table don't use any procedure function etc.

And only when I update or insert from the application I can see this behavior.

**UPDATE**

```
urls.py
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^recepcion/$','prov.views.DetRecView',name='recepcion'),
    url(r'^newdetrec/$','prov.views.NewDetRecView',name='newdetrec'),
    url(r'^master/$','prov.views.NewMasterView',name='master'),
    url(r'^conci/$', 'prov.views.ConciView',name='conci'),
    url(r'^carga/$', 'prov.views.CargaView',name='carga'),
    url(r'^gencert/$', 'prov.views.GenCertView',name='gencert'),
    url(r'^entcert/$', 'prov.views.EntCertView',name='entcert'),
    url(r'^aceptacert/$', 'prov.views.AceptaCertView',name='aceptacert'),
    url(r'^envconci/$', 'prov.views.EnvConciView',name='envconci'),
)
```

My create view (for the same model)

```
  @login_required(login_url='/login/')
    @permission_required('prov.views.configView',login_url='/login/')
    def NewDetRecView(request):
        form = NewDetRecForm(request.POST or None)
        if request.method == 'POST':
           idp = request.POST['id_proveedor']
           a = request.POST['anio']
           m = request.POST['mes']
           id = Proveedor.objects.get(id_proveedor=idp)
           obj,created = DetalleRecepcion.objects.get_or_create(id_proveedor=id,anio=a,mes=m)
           obj.save()
           return HttpResponseRedirect('/monitor/')

           if not created:
              obj.id_proveedor = id
              obj.anio = a
              obj.mes = m
              obj.save()
              return HttpResponseRedirect('/monitor/')
        return render_to_response('newdetrec.html',
                              {'form':form})
```

My form class to create new records:

```
class NewDetRecForm(forms.ModelForm):
      def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
       super(NewDetRecForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
       self.helper = FormHelper(self)
       self.helper.layout.append(Submit('save','Grabar'))
       self.helper.layout = Layout(
        Fieldset('',
                 'id_proveedor',
                 'anio',
                 'mes',
                 Submit('save','Grabar'),
                )
       )
      def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(NewDetRecForm, self).clean()

        id_proveedor = self.cleaned_data['id_proveedor']
        #num_archivos = self.cleaned_data['num_archivos']
        anio = self.cleaned_data['anio']
        mes = self.cleaned_data['mes']

        qs = self.Meta.model.objects.filter(id_proveedor=id_proveedor, anio=anio, mes=mes)
        if self.instance:
            qs = qs.exclude(pk = self.instance.pk)
        if qs.count() > 0:
            raise forms.ValidationError(u'Registro ya existente')

        return cleaned_data
      class Meta:
        model = DetalleRecepcion
```

DetRecForm is for update

DetRecView is for update

NewDetRecForm is for create

NewDetRecView is for create

**UPDATE 2**

javascript function to pass parameters

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready ( function () {
    $(document).on ("click", "#recepcion", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var tbl = document.getElementById("myTable");
        var idpro = $(this).parents('tr:first').find('td:first').text();
        var anio = $(this).closest('tr').children(":eq(1)").text();
        var mes = $(this).closest('tr').children(":eq(2)").text();
        var argu = "?i="+idpro+"&a="+anio+"&m="+mes;
        //window.location = "/recepcion/"+argu;
        var url = "/recepcion/"+argu;
        window.open(url,'_blank')
    });
});
</script>
```

I know this isn't the right way to pass parameters to the templates.
I am start learning AJAX to pass the data, but meanwhile I use this horrible function

Comment: Can you show your `urls`?

Comment: And you should set `instance` to your `form_class` when object have to be updated, but not when it have to be created

Comment: I paste part of my urls. I am beginning to learn DJANGO and I made a lot of newbie errors. How can I set the instance in the form_class.

Answer (score 0):

```
url(r'^recepcion/add/$','prov.views.DetRecView',name='recepcion_add'),  # create object
url(r'^recepcion/edit/(?P<pk>\d+)/$','prov.views.DetRecView',name='recepcion_edit'),  # update object
```

Lets look at your condition in the view function: `if request.method=='POST'` better use `if request.POST`,

So when you have `else` - it means `request.GET` you get an instance of `DetalleRecepcion` (read instance as object of some class) and pass it to your ModelForm. It is **update** object approach (but you use this to **create** object), and provided query must give one object (unique).

If you want use this view to **create** and **update** you have to change your urls (smth like I did above) and you have to define condition: `if request.kwargs.get('pk')` you're going to **update** object `else` you're going to **create** object.

Main difference that if it is **update** case you have to provide instance to your form `r = DetalleRecepcion.objects.get(pk=request.kwargs['pk'])`, so  `DetRecForm(instance=r)` (when`request.GET`) and  `form = DetRecForm(request.POST, instance =r)` (when`request.POST`).

If you want provide some initial data to your form (when `request.GET`) use `DetRecForm(initial = {'id_proveedor': idp, 'anio': anio, 'mes': mes, 'usuario': request.user})`

Comment: I use this view only to update records and i create a different view to create records. The users must update the records, but only the admin(Me) can create new records. I will update the post and you can check my create view. Creating or updating I get duplicated rows inserted. And THANKS man.

Comment: You should update your code in question due recommendation above (and why you use `get_or_create` if you have a form `form.save()`).

Comment: I will follow your recomendations and I am using get_or_create because I get the exception that the id_proveedor already exist. This is a legacy database and I get some issues for the primarys and foreigns keys. I will delete the .save() line

Comment: Sorry bother you, but I have a question for you @madzohan. How can I pass parameters from a HTML table to a template. I think my problem is the way how I pass the parameters to the edit form template. At fisrt I get a lot of error trying to pass values from a html table rendered with django-tables2 to the edit forms. I finally make this with a horrible javascript function. I paste the function I am using to pass the parameters in the post.

Comment: django-tables2 render queryset as html table on your template, so all rendered data you have first in your view queryset. So I don't understand what you mean "How can I pass parameters from a HTML table to a template" because it is already there. What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: Take some cell values and pass it as parameter to the edit form. the table are rendered without any problem. In the tabla I have a dropdown button with several options, one options use the edit form and view definition. I need to take the value of the first three columns(id_proveedor,anio,mes) and send it as parameters to the edit form of the model DetalleRecepcion. You can see in the JS function I am not using get or post method to the parameters. In others words i can get the value from table cells that I need but I don't know how to pass it as arguments to the edit form

Comment: Calling `window.open(url,'_blank')` you create `GET` request to your view. It will be better if you wrap your `td`s (in each `tr`) by `form` and each `td` value by `input`, in this case you can submit form (it will be faster then js). But for that you need override default django-tables2 template.

Comment: How can only convert to input text the first three columns

Comment: override default django-tables2 template and set it on your view `table = table_class(filter_obj.qs, template='common/tables/my_table.html')
        context['table'] = table`

Comment: also you can customise rendering of model field by `TemplateColumn`

Comment: Thanks, But I don't know why my view definition update all the records who had the same id_proveedor. I try using `unique_together ("id_proveedor,"anio,"mes")` and the always update all the records with the same id_proveedor.